# EXCELL VBA, if the timer end then the userform will close

Tags: excel, vba, userform, countdowntimer

This is the timer codes

```
Sub StartTimer()
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), _
"Decrement_Count_By_1"
End Sub
```

Then, the countdown

```
Sub Decrement_Count_By_1()
StartTimer
Range("Z1").Value = Range("Z1").Value - TimeValue("00:00:01")
UserForm5.Label7.Caption = Format(Range("Z1").Value, "hh:mm:ss")
If Range("Z1").Value = "00:00::01" Then
End If
On Error Resume Next
If Range("Z1").Value = 0 Then
End If
End Sub



Sub resettimer()
If Range("Z1").Value = 0 Then
        Range("Z1").Value = ("00:01:00")
End If
End Sub
```

Then, how to make userform close when the timer ends? Please help me, thankyouu

Comment: [This may be useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/unload-statement)

Comment: Have you tried `UserForm5.Hide` (or `Unload UserForm5`, depending on what "closing the form" actually stands for) in that no-op conditional block where you check if Z1 is 0? That said if the cell's initial value (regardless of its formatted text) contains a date part (there's no "time" data type), then its value is never going to reach 0; either only verify that the *decimal portion* of the cell's value is 0, or compare `"00:00:00"` the `.Text` instead of the `.Value`, but then note that this makes the logic dependent on the cell's `NumberFormat`, which is likely locale-dependent.